# Creating an object in another class's function causing loop?

Tags: c++, function, class, loops, game-engine

I am using c++ and the Irrlicht engine to create a game for a university project, and I've run into a problem.

I have a class called World, that sets up the engine and loads in the map, and the Main class creates an object of this class, and the constructor is called creating the world and setting up the engine (This all works fine!).

However, now I have created a Player class that will set up the camera. The code I have to set up the camera works ***fine*** if it is in the same class as `World`: if I create a function in the class `World` and call that function in the constructor, all is well. However, whenever I put this code into the `Player` class, and then create an object of Player in the `World` constructor, it causes an infinite loop of the constructor for the class `World`.

I don't want to stick all the function in the class `World`, as splitting it up would be a lot neater!

World.cpp & World.h = http://pastebin.com/qtTsGQAR

Player.cpp & World.h = http://pastebin.com/DR7aUiYf

Comment: Please post the code here, not all networks allow access to pastebin.

Comment: Questions have to be self-contained. It's ok to link to additional data, but that must be strictly supplementary, like showing the code live on an online-compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Player` inherits from `World`, then to create a `Player`, you must create a `World`, and that creates a `Player`, which creates a `World`, and so on ad infinitum.

The solution is to not have `Player`inherit from `World`.
What would it even *mean* that a player were a world?
It doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: The reason I made Player inherit from World was to use the engine functions that are set up in World.h, to create the camera for the player I need to use the pointers that are made in World.h, is there anyway to make these pointers global across classes?

Comment: @Sjk You can pass them to the player object's constructor, or to the player's member functions. You *can* make them global, and experiencing the mess that makes is a good way to learn to avoid it, but global data is usually not the right path to take. Perhaps they don't even belong in the World class? (In general, don't inherit just to access data or code - inherit because one thing really *is like* another thing.)

Comment: Awesome, I shall play around and try learn some more from here! Been fun learning so far. Thanks for your help buddy.

Comment: Dude! I just got it working! Passing it through player object's constructor! YESSS! Literally best feeling in the world getting something to work. Onwards and upwards! Haha, thanks again x10000 dude!

Answer (score 0):

Your Player class subclasses the World class.

```
class Player: public World
{
  public:
     Player();
    ~Player();

  private:
     void setup_player();
};
```

By creating a Player class, the constructor of World is invoked. However, your World constructor creates an instance of Player class:

```
World::World()
{

    setup_engine();
    //open up the file path
    //std::fstream fin(file_path);
    //std::string command;

    //open up the world
    std::cout << "* Constructing World" << std::endl;
    //loading the first level scene
            smgr->loadScene("..\\Assets\\firstLevel.irr");
            std::cout << "** Constructing Complete" << std::endl;

            Player playerone;



}
```

Then, the constructor of a World class is invoked, and so forth.